# Bokeh module names can't be found in Atom IDE

Tags: layout, server, atom-editor, bokeh

I put a .py using ATOM IDE, called the .py in cmd command and got the following error saying that the module can't be found: **Trackback (most recent call last): File "widgets.py", line 5, in  from bokeh.layouts import layout ImportError: No module named layouts.**

The same syntax ran fine in Jupyter...without warning for layouts module name.

Anyone has a clue? Is it possible my Python version and the bokeh version are compatible?

The code in widgets.py is the following:

```
    from bokeh.io import output_file, show
    #create text box on webpage, and text
    from bokeh.models.widgets import TextInput, Button, Paragraph
    #arrange the widgets
    from bokeh.layouts import layout
```

Answer (score 0):

After a bit investigation, I found that it's because I was using the cmd command line rather than the Anaconda Prompt environment. Now I am in the correct environment, the .py code generates a bokeh server as it is supposed to.